# SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'VARBINARY' from a data value of type 'VARCHAR'

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to set the values ​​of the parameters in the following Hibernate query:

```
public List<Transactions> getTransactions(long cardNum, String type) {
    Query q1 = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM bank.persistence.entity.Transactions WHERE PK_CRED_CARD_ID=:CardID AND TRANSACTION_TYPE=:trType");
    q1.setParameter("CardID", cardNum);
    q1.setParameter("trType", type);
    return q1.list();
}
```

But I am getting the following error, the problem seems to be with the value of the String type:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: An attempt was made to get a data value of type 'VARBINARY' from a data value of type 'VARCHAR'.
```

Here is the Transactions entity class:

```
package bank.persistence.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Transactions implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_TYPE")
    private String transType;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private float amt;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String desr;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_DATE")
    private Date tranDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PK_ACCT_ID")
    private Account account;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PK_CRED_CARD_ID")
    private CreditCard credCard;

    // getter and setter for all attributes

}
```

Comment: Dear ktj, have you checked that the parameters you are setting are getting 'null' values?

Comment: @kjt - Check my answer and try that out.

Comment: accept the answer which solved your problem, so that it'll be known that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I think datatypes gave by you in entity and database are different.Make they both are same.
In the entity make it as `String`

```
@Column(name = "TRANSACTION_TYPE" type="String")
```

i think one of the cardNum , type is null

Comment: following the part of transaction class : data type is String here



    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_TYPE")
    private String transType;

Comment: @ktj  i think one of the cardNum , type is null

Answer (score 0):

Since its HQL, should your query be something like this:-

```
Query q1 = factory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM bank.persistence.entity.Transactions T 
WHERE T.credCard.id=:CardID AND T.transType=:trType");
```

You need to give the variables which are mapped to the columns. Not the column names directly.
I'm assuming the ID column in `CreditCard` table to be id. If not, change it to whatever is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If All the type are fine than check if the value you are setting in setParameter() is null  in which case hibernate will throw this error.